# Rotation on the unit circle K

Tags: complex-numbers

If $\{a^{n}:n\in\mathbb{Z}\}$ is dense on the  unite circle K, then $\{a^{n}:n< 0\}$ is also dense on K. How to prove this result?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the powers of $a$ are dense, for every $\epsilon$ there's an $n\ne0$ such that $a^n$ is within $\epsilon$ of $1$. If $n\lt0$, then for every point $p$ on the circle there's a positive $k$ such that $a^{nk}$ is within $\epsilon$ of $p$. If $n\gt0$, then there's a negative $k$ such that $a^{nk}$ is within $\epsilon$ of $p$. Either way, $nk\lt0$.

Comment: could you please give more details

Comment: Sure. Just let me know what details you want.

Comment: how can you make sure that there's a positive k such that $a_n^k$ is within $ϵ$ of p.

Comment: If $a^n$ is within $\epsilon$ of $1$, then each of the numbers $1,a^n,a^{2n},a^{3n},dots$ is within $\epsilon$ of the next. You're going around the unit circle, taking steps of size less than $\epsilon$. So, you come within $\epsilon$ of every point $p$ on the circle.